# How can I use count in query to count 0 if data is empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I use count in query, to count 0 if data is empty

I've 3 tables user,parent,checkin log

```
 user table
    id | name    | type
    1  | aion    | student
    2  | marry   | teacher
    3  | terst   | student

parent table
id | user_id | teacher_id
1  |   1     |  2
2  |   3     |  2

checkin_log table
id | user_id | type_attendence
1  |  1      |  late
2  |  3      |  absence


 DB::table("parent AS p")
->leftJoin('users AS u', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->leftJoin('checkin_log AS c', 'p.user_id', '=', 'c.user_id')
->select('u.id','u.name', DB::raw('COUNT(c.type_attendance) as total'))
->where('p.teacher_id',2)
->where(function ($q) {
                        $q->where('c.type_attendance', 'absence')
                    })
->groupBy('u.id')
->get()->toArray();
```

as this query  It print only data that has type_attendance It w'll display

```
id | name | total
3  | terst|   1
```

how can I count if empty `'c.type_attendance' = 'absence'` show `total = 0` I want display like :

```
id | name | total
1  | aion |   0
3  | terst|   1
```

**NOTE :** I need to use `where('c.type_attendance', 'absence')`  because I want to count absence in each student

Comment: Move the attendance condition in to the left join

Comment: any example I never use condition in left join before @Strawberry

Comment: I don't know laravel syntax, but in raw it would be `left join y on y.col = x.col and y.type = 'my_type'`

Comment: Oh i can do it in mysql sever thanks.I still find how it's work with laravel.Can you please post your answer I'll mark @Strawberry

Comment: I try to avoid answering questions that fail to provide proper MCVEs- but if you want to answer and accept, then feel free to go right ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) of mysql.

```
DB::table("parent AS p")
->leftJoin('users AS u', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->leftJoin('checkin_log AS c', 'p.user_id', '=', 'c.user_id')
->select('u.id','u.name', DB::raw('IFNULL(COUNT(c.type_attendance),0) as total'))
->where('p.teacher_id',2)
->where(function ($q) {
                        $q->where('c.type_attendance', 'absence')
                    })
->groupBy('u.id')
->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: @TryHardz I glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

This method also work

```
DB::table("parent AS p")
->leftJoin('users AS u', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->leftJoin('checkin_log AS c', function($join)
                    {
                        $join->on('p.user_id', '=', 'c.user_id')
                        ->where('c.type_attendance','abcense');
                    })
->select('u.id','u.name', DB::raw('COUNT(c.type_attendance) as total'))
->where('p.teacher_id',2)
->groupBy('u.id')
->get()->toArray();
```